# Default values for TypedDict

Tags: python, typeddict

Let's consider I have the following TypedDict:

```py
class A(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int
```

What is the best practice for setting default values for this class?

I tried to add a constructor but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
class A(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int
    def __init__(self):
        TypedDict.__init__(self)
        a = 0
        b = 1
```

EDIT:
I don't want to use dataclass because I need to serialize and deserialize to JSON files and dataclasses have some problem with it.

What do you think?

Comment: So you are trying to Type a dictionary in python as descrribed in https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/. If i understand correctly this should only be used for type hints

Comment: You can't have anything except for the definitions in [Class-based Syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#class-based-syntax). Why do you need default values?

Comment: I'd simply use `pydantic.BaseModel` instead (if possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TypedDict` is only for specifying that a `dict` follows a certain layout, not an actual class. You can of course use a `TypedDict` to create an **instance** of that specific layout but it doesn't come with defaults.

One possible solution is to add a *factory* method to the class.
You could use this *factory* method instead to set defaults.

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class A(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, a: int = 0, b: int = 1) -> A:
        return A(a=a, b=b)

a = A.create(a=4)
# {"a": 4, "b": 1}
```

If having a `dict` is not a strict requirement then [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is good having small objects with defaults.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 0
    b: int = 1
```

If you need to create a dictionary from them, you can use `asdict`

```py
from dataclasses import asdict

a = A(a=4)
asdict(a)  # {"a": 4, "b": 1}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm working with dicts and  I need to store objects in JSON files. dataclasses have problems with serialization and it looks weird to have both dataclass and TypedDict with the same attributes only for load/dump to file

Comment: You should add the extra constraint into the question! I updated my answer to suggest another method.

Comment: FYI I don't think the factory method solution is valid now. It will trigger a "TypedDict classes can contain only type annotations" type checking error. Some discussion on this topic here: 

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/6517